# Phalcon PHP: model validation() function?

Tags: php, validation, model, phalcon

In my model, I'm including the function validation().  It doesn't seem to be getting hit.  I have something similar to this:

```
class People extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function validation() {
        die('here');
    }
}

$person = new People();
$person->name = 'Bob';
$person->save();
```

But the validation function never gets called.  Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works only for existing model records.
If you want to validate on create, you could use **beforeValidationOnCreate()** method.
You can visit [phalcon Documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/reference/models.html#events-and-events-manager) for all events.

Comment: Hm.  Didn't know that.  "validation()" actually isn't listed with the events.  I think it should be named something else if it only works for update events...  Either way, thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find a reference to this being fixed/changed, but validation() is called for create and update with 2.0.10. It is still missing from the events table though.